# send (alsa) audio via network via UDP

Tags: alsa, netcat, fifo

This to my understanding records mono in wav format for 300 seconds to a named pipe called "mic_rec"

```
rec arecord -D hw:4,0 -d 300 -f cd -t wav -c 1 mic_rec
```

And this sends whatever it finds in the named pipe "mic_rec" via tcp out to port 8111

```
cat mic_rec |netcat -l -p 8111
```

UDP

```
cat mic_rec |netcat -u -l -p 8111
```

receiving with TCP (works):

```
netcat 192.168.2.29 8111 |vlc -
```

receiving with UDP (does not):

```
netcat -u 192.168.2.29 8111 |vlc -
```

This (using TCP) works but it has about 2 seconds of delay. So my first idea was just switching to UDP with the -u parameter. But this does not seem to work, I can't hear anything on the receiving end. What did I miss?

Pulseaudio seems to have an easier way to do this. But to my knowledge the device I use (NanoPi Neo 1.4) does not support that.

Comment: Your latency is mainly from internal buffer of netcat. Try to lower it to minimum.

Comment: This was definitely a valuable tip and the reduction of delay is probably good enough for my current use case. Are there other downsides to using TCP here?

Comment: In the case of a stream of audio samples, UDP has a couple of very negative characteristics.  It doesn't guarantee delivery of all datagrams (packets) containing data, so there's a risk of dropouts.  UDP also doesn't guarantee the order which datagrams are received, so the audio stream can be corrupted.  If your network is an idle LAN like Ethernet between your send and receive points, it can work well.  But congestion in the network (common the public Internet) can wreak havoc on the sound.  And the latency difference between TCP and UDP is too small to be worthwhile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using UDP will not necessarily *by itself* solve the problem with latency. This answer just tries to explain why your attempt with UDP did not work at all.

UDP is a connectionless protocol, there is no handshake. This means your `netcat` that "listens" (`netcat -l`) does not know where to send data to, *until* it receives something from your `netcat` (or whatever) that "connects". Your `netcat` that "connects" does not send anything by itself though.

Send something, anything from the `netcat` that "connects". Without changing your commands, you can do this by typing something (in the terminal where it runs) and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>; try it. Alternatively, modify the command and pipe `echo foo` to `netcat`, so it sends `foo` without waiting for any input from you:

```
echo foo | netcat -u 192.168.2.29 8111 | vlc -
```

The "listening" `netcat` will print `foo`. Frankly sole `echo` instead of `echo foo` is enough, it prints one newline character that will get to the "listening" `netcat` that will notice where it came from.

This way the "listening" `netcat` will learn where to send data to and it will start doing it.

With TCP there is no such problem because the listening end learns the address and the port of the connecting end during handshake, before any actual data is sent in any direction.

Comment: definitely upvoted and I think I will mark this as the answer. And you where right. It does even seem to have a higher latency as TCP with small buffer. But according to help of netcat UDP will ignore buffer size parameter. So how do we to this? I mark this as the answer and ask another question on how to reduce the latency?

Comment: @Daniel When there is an explicit question (and there always should be one), I usually try to answer it, even if there's an underlying problem (see [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)). In your case it's "this does not seem to work, I can't hear anything on the receiving end. What did I miss?". I answered exactly this. So yes, in my opinion you should ask a separate question and ask explicitly about latency there.

Comment: I agree. Just wanted to confirm if I correctly interpreted the SE etiquette.